# saving array in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

import datetime
```

so i have got these three arrays

```
a = ['1','2','3','5']

b = ['a','b','c','d']

c = ['asdf','23f23','234234','234231sxd']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['NameA','NameB','NameC'])

df = df.append({'NameA':a,'NameB':b,'NameC':c},ignore_index = True)

save = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

save1 = save+'.csv'

print save1

df.to_csv(save1)
```

using pandas, if i save as csv file, it looks like this

```
     NameA                   NameB                   NameC
0   ['1', '2', '3', '5']    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']    ['asdf', '23f23', '234234',  234231sxd']
```

can you please show me how to allocate each strings in each arrays to different columns into an excel as per format below
sorry about the format

```
       NameA NameB NameC

0      1     a     asdf

1      2     b     23f23

2      3     c     234234

3      5     d     234231sxd
```

Comment: Can you format your question so that the bits that are code look like code and also the output. You can select a block of text in the editor and press `ctrl + k` to mark it as code, also remove the extraneous lines so its more compact, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved without the call to df.append as per the [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) constructor.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NameA':a,'NameB':b,'NameC':c})
```